# Kotlin foreach return list

Tags: kotlin

simple question, is there a method for a collection to apply action on every element (like foreach) but who return the list

I can write it myself :

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.myforEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Iterable<T> {
   for (element in this) action(element)
        
   return this
}
```

But it must already exist

Comment: _onEach { ... }_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is [onEach](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/on-each.html) for this:

```
val sameList = list.onEach { doStuff() }
```